# Stub a method added by a plugin on an ActiveRecord class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, stub

I'm using the plugin acts_as_audited on the User model. So i have the following in user.rb -

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_audited
end
```

I know that the plugin acts_as_audited works, as it has its own unit tests.

I want to stub the call of "acts_as_audited" in my own specs, as everytime I create a user or make changes it to, acts_as_audited does its thing, and audits every change.

My tests would run much faster if I could stub out the acts_as_audited call so that it doesn't hit the database.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's anything built-in to acts_as_audited to stub the plugin, but there was a feature request to do so:

https://github.com/collectiveidea/acts_as_audited/issues/18

One solution is to write a hook to avoid writes to the DB if a static class variable is false:

```
module CollectiveIdea::Acts::Audited::InstanceMethods
  private
    def write_audit(attrs)
      self.audits.create attrs if auditing_enabled && Audit.auditing_enabled?
    end
end

class Audit
  @@auditing_enabled = true
  def self.auditing_enabled?
    @@auditing_enabled
  end

  def self.disable_auditing
    @@auditing_enabled = false
  end

  def self.enable_auditing
    @@auditing_enabled = true
  end
end
```